# geocoder.geocode callback is never called in ionic cordova

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework, geocode

I have a ionic/cordova android project where I try to fetch the location for some coordinates inside a service; maps sdk is loaded alright and in my service, I have the following:

```
var lat = 30;  // example
var lng = 32;  // example
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  // geocoder is not undefined here
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    console.log("geocoder.geocode callback"); // never printed ...
});
```

In the HTML, the API is loaded like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&key=MOBILE_API_KEY"></script>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

**[EDIT]**

I tried removing the key argument from the script loading url; no changes there; accessing the app through the browser, geocoder.geocode worked alright; running it with the android emulator or in an android device, it did not work. Could this be permission related or something?

By the way, my content-security-policy is set as follow, for now:

**[EDIT2]**

Just made an pen with a ionic project example; create a project with:

```
ionic start TheBlank blank
```

and copy the code. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPxNaL

```
// add the android platform 
ionic platform add android 
// run the project on device
ionic run android // geocode callback will not work here
ionic serve // geocode callback will work here
```

Comment: hard to say, the code you've given looks valid. Possibly it's something else wrong in the actual code. Can you add a link to some code on jsfiddle or somewhere that demonstrates the full code, enough at least to show where the problem might be?

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Also, have you taken a look at this plugin? https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin/wiki/Geocoder

Comment: not_a_bot, I tried to capture error messages, but no, I don't get any error (that I know of). There is a missing configuration for my example:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' *"/>

Comment: I have not, not_a_bot; the goal is to do this without an plugin; nonetheless, there is new info on the subject: If I try to call geocode running ionic from the web browser, I get the correct result; running it from the emulator or device, I don't, the callback is never called.

Comment: I'm starting to suspect this could be a permission related problem. I made a simple example using google maps and the map only loads in the browser. When running in the device, it simply doesn't load the map.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was somehow related to ionic. After using cordova to run and emulate, things started working. I tested this with the ionic-starter-maps template. To do it yourself, try this:

```
ionic start MyMaps maps
ionic platform add android
ionic emulate android  # won't work

ionic start MyMaps maps
cordova platform add android
cordova emulate android  # works!
```

Also, make sure content-security-policy has the required rules:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
        default-src 'self' data: gap:
            https://ssl.gstatic.com;
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
            https://maps.gstatic.com https://maps.googleapis.com;
        img-src     'self'
            https://maps.gstatic.com https://maps.googleapis.com;
        style-src   'self' 'unsafe-inline' *;
        media-src   *;">
```